# How to filter the query by date in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

The query did not return any information, either by Timestamp or Date or String.

```
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.now();

    db.collection("entregas")
            .whereLessThan("createdAt", timestamp)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                    entrega = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Entrega.class);
                    todasEntregas.add(entrega);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Print with firebase structure:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Zpa.png)

Comment: Are you importing com.google.firebase.Timestamp or using any other implementation of Timestamp?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Adjusted post and I'm using com.google.firebase.Timestamp  @UlisesTorrella

Comment: I added the structure @AlexMamo

Comment: Is that `Timestamp` object a Firestore Timestamp object?